# Why plot with line doesn't work with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a profile of temperature using line.
My code :

```
set multiplot layout 2,2 rowsfirst

p for [i=1:5] './phi=0.0'.i.'/Field/Fields_1.00e+04_800.dat' u ($2==-5e-07?$1:1/0):4 w l lw 2 t 'phi=0.0'.i

p for [i=1:5] './phi=0.0'.i.'/Field/Fields_1.00e+04_800.dat' u ($2==-5e-07?$1:1/0):3 w lp t 'phi=0.0'.i

p for [i=1:5] './phi=0.0'.i.'/Field/Fields_1.00e+04_800.dat' u ($2==-5e-07?$1:1/0):6 w lp t 'phi=0.0'.i

p for [i=1:5] './phi=0.0'.i.'/Field/Fields_1.00e+04_800.dat' u ($2==-5e-07?$1:1/0):5 w lp t 'phi=0.0'.i

unset multiplot
```

What I get :

[image: the output]

As you can see on the first plot, nothing appears and I don't understand why ?

My data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ZvG4OsKfqMKavL7VsxLn5w688hvGfLH/view?usp=sharing

Is due to the blanks lines ?

Thank you !

Comment: "Is due to the blanks lines ?" Blank lines can do that, so you would have data with different line segments.

Comment: I remove blank lines but the problem remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

I guess it is a combination of filtered data and blank lines and the plotting style `with lines`.

One possible solution:

1. remove the blank lines
2. and before your plotting commands add a line `set datafile missing NaN`

There are other solutions in case you don't want to change your original data files.

Comment: Adding set datafile missing NaN works

Comment: yes, in your special case you need both: removing blank lines **and** `set datafile missing NaN`. Either the one **or** the other will not work.